# How to filter a column in Google sheets with the criteria: if it contains numbers (the cells are strings)?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, filter, filtering

Google Sheets have some filters  'greater than etc' but that applies if the column has been formatted as numbers. In my case, the column content are strings.

Is there a regex or any other way of filtering a column ?

I tried things like "\d+", or ".*[0-9].*" as the "custom formula" (in the built in filter function of google sheet), but it did not work.

I was expecting that when I apply the filter it filters the column by displaying the rows that respect the filter applied to the given column.

Comment: Does the cells contains numbers & letters, and you want to filter the data with only the numbers? Or the cells only contains numbers, but is format as string?